# Выгрузка определенных заголовков из join'а

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Я не совсем отлично разбираюсь в SQL, но нужно выгрузить заголовки из двух таблиц через JOIN, но, заголовки пересекаются как в одной и второй. Как правильно подбить запрос для выгрузки нескольких заголовков из первой, и два из второй?

Comment: Вопрос совершенно непонятен. Какие ещё заголовки? имена полей, что ли? ну так почитайте, что такое алиасы и для чего они...

Answer (score 0):

Через явную привязку. Например:

```
SELECT
   t1.p1,
   t1.p2,
   t1.p3,
   t2.p1,
   t2.p2
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN table_2 AS t2
ON t1.p4=t2.p3
```